# Force all errors to a custom error page in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, http-status-codes, cakephp-2.x

I'm trying to force all of my errors to a single custom page in Cakephp(2.0) but most of the tutorials that I find are for very specific error codes. I want it to show just a single error page so what I first did was to point all of the errors of specific error status to a single error page. But after further testing, I noticed that other codes were not being captured.

I need my code to capture all of the http error codes to a single error page.

This is my code:

```
Configure::write('Exception', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
    'renderer' => 'AppExceptionRenderer',
    'log' => true
));
```

And my AppExceptionRenderer:

```
<?php 
 App::uses('ExceptionRenderer', 'Error');

class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {

public function internalError($error) {
$this->controller->beforeFilter();
$this->controller->set('title_for_layout', 'Internal Server Error');
$this->controller->render('/Errors/error500');
$this->controller->response->send();

... All the other error handlers are similar to this, but very limited since there are a lot of client and server errors 
} ?>
```

My template pages seems to be working just fine, so I did not include it.

How do I alter the code to cover every http status code instead? Or is it not possible?

Comment: When you finished development and go to [deploy your CakePHP application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/deployment.html) you should change `debug` level in the `core.php` to `0`. After this change there are by default only two error states, 404 or 500. So what other error status codes are you talking about exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the following methods:

```
ExceptionRenderer::error400($error) 
ExceptionRenderer::error500($error)
```

Alternatively, you can override **ExceptionRenderer:_outputMessage($template)** with something like:

```
protected function _outputMessage($template) {
    $this->controller->layout = 'my_error';
    parent::_outputMessage($template);
}
```

And add the file /app/View/Layouts/my_error.ctp as a new custom layout.